# Switching Organizations in Apple Developer Center

Tags: iphone, ios, developer-program, app-store-connect

I have my own iOS Developer account and recently I got invited to join a team. I accepted, but now I can't switch back to my personal account to develop apps for myself. Every time I log in it has the Organization set to that team.

How can I switch back to my own developer center area??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have an Apple ID for my multiple work accounts.  When I sign in, I see:

[image: Team Select Screen]

I'm not sure why you aren't seeing it, if you have two teams on the same Apple ID.

Comment: I don't see how to get to this page other than manually typing the URL, but it does work! (assuming you're in multiple teams) https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/selectTeam.action

Answer (score 2):

As the solution suggested by Alan does no longer work for me, I investigated a bit and found out the team switching option is now located under *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles*, but still has no clickable link to it.

The URL is now:
https://developer.apple.com/account/selectTeam.action

**Update**
It appears, the following URL is also working:
https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/selectTeam.action

Comment: Does not work if currently selected team has expired membership

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/selectTeam.action)  that max shared is valid but I was wondering how to get the team switching option without knowing the url.

I found that for now on, Apple needs you to logout from the Member Center and then when you log back in, you see a switching option before the dashboard.

Comment: still i dont have option to switch teams

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do it:

[image: switching between teams]

click your name on the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two Apple ID to have distinct roles within Xcode and within the developer portal.

I would get in contact with Developer Support before making a new account to be sure you have all the steps correct as well as have them verify what you think has happened to your current account. It's better to get confirmation before making changes in my experience.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/